# What type of accent does this person have?

Tags: american-english, accent, rhoticity, hiberno-english, kenyan-english

My friend has lived in Kenya for the first 8 years of his life and the United States for 2 & 1/2 years. He's been in Ireland since 2009.

He is auditioning for a voiceover job on the radio and they would like him to describe his accent. I had a hard time pinning it down.

https://vocaroo.com/aKPfKojiOvC

Comment: He appears to have a base American accent from somewhere near the Canadian border (possibly central). It is overlaid with an Irish (the Republic - possibly Dublin) accent that he has picked up in the last 9 years.

Comment: Upper midwest USA accent, near Canada, as in Washington, Michigan, Wisconsin (esp) -- with touches of Irish.

Comment: I'd agree with both of those assessments, but to confirm the upper midwest tag, I'd like to hear him pronounce two vowels. One would be the "a" in the word "car". The other would be the "o" in "God", "got", or "problem". These "o"s may not all be the same in standard US English, but in that part of the US they are pronounced similarly. These vowels really distinguish that accent. If you could provide another short recording with those vowels, it would be very helpful.